# .NET FirebaseAuthProvider

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, firebase-authentication

I wrote a service for authenticating users with firebase. However, I am getting null pointer exception inside FirebaseAuthLink when it is time to refresh the authentication

The exception is thrown at `_authLink = await _authLink.GetFreshAuthAsync();` inside my GetFreshUserAsync function, but _authLink is not null. I have run through it with the debugger and when the null pointer exception is thrown _authlink is not null yet the exception is thrown anyway. if serializedAuthLink is null an exception is also thrown and caught as expected. So it is not possible for _authlink to be null. So I am guessing a property FirebaseAuthLink depends on is, but I don't know which one.

**Full Service Code**

```
public class FirebaseAuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
{
    public UserModel UserModel { get; set; }

    private readonly string FIREBASE_KEY= "<<--MY_KEY_HIDDEN_FOR_STACKOVEFLOW-->>";
    private FirebaseAuthProvider _authProvider;
    private FirebaseAuthLink _authLink;

    public FirebaseAuthenticationService()
    {
        _authProvider = new FirebaseAuthProvider(new FirebaseConfig(FIREBASE_KEY));
    }

    public async Task<ResultModel<UserModel>> Login(UserModel user)
    {
        try
        {
            _authLink = await _authProvider.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(user.Email, user.Password);

            string serializedAuthLink = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_authLink);

            await SecureStorage.SetAsync(ConfigConst.FIREBASE_USER_AUTHLINK, serializedAuthLink);

            ResultModel<UserModel> userResult = await GetFreshUserAsync();

            return userResult;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new ResultModel<UserModel>(false) { Message = e.Message };
        }

    }

    public Task<ResultModel<bool>> Logout()
    {
        Preferences.Remove(ConfigConst.FIREBASE_USER_AUTHLINK);

        return Task.FromResult(new ResultModel<bool>(true));
    }

    public async Task<ResultModel<bool>> Register(UserModel user)
    {
        try
        {
            await _authProvider.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(user.Email, user.Password, user.Name);

            return new ResultModel<bool>(true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new ResultModel<bool>(false) { Message = ex.Message };
        }
    }

    public async Task<ResultModel<UserModel>> GetFreshUserAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_authLink is null)
            {
                var serializedAuthLink = await SecureStorage.GetAsync(ConfigConst.FIREBASE_USER_AUTHLINK);

                _authLink = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FirebaseAuthLink>(serializedAuthLink);
            }

            _authLink = await _authLink.GetFreshAuthAsync();

            User fu = await _authProvider.GetUserAsync(_authLink.FirebaseToken);

            UserModel = new UserModel()
            {
                Id = fu.LocalId,
                Email = fu.Email,
                Name = fu.DisplayName,
                JWT_Token = _authLink.FirebaseToken
            };

            return new ResultModel<UserModel>(true) { Content = UserModel };
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Preferences.Remove(ConfigConst.FIREBASE_USER_AUTHLINK);
            return new ResultModel<UserModel>(false) { Message = e.Message };
        }
    }
}
```